# Adhoc file installing from iTunes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, installation

Not able to install the Adhoc iPA file to my iPhone 4s, it got installed for 3 times to test and then the problem happened automatically. I have checkout my git repository till the last working date, but still the same problem after trying to install.

I get the below image after sync it from iTunes

I can't post the image because of the restriction from the stackoverflow :)

Icon
installing...

Can anybody tell me what is going on?
I have re-checked the Provision profiles and also created a new profile to double check if there was a problem from the certificate but still the same problem. It never get install.

Comment: Check you have added Device UDID in certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **delete the app completely** from your phone, then install again. Sometimes the adhoc update has problems with over-installing over an existing app and gives you some strange results.